# SQL SERVER select statement doesn't seem to be able to select more than one column

Tags: php, sql, database, sqlsrv

I am currently using SQL server 2008. I am getting very frustrated because my select statement does not seem to be able to select more than one column. Each time I select from my database table, it displays nothing.

My coding is as follows:

```
<?php
// build a query to select records from table authorisation to echo out all queries
$query1  = "SELECT * FROM authorisation  ";

// execute the query you created above and store the result in a php variable
$result1 = sqlsrv_query($con, $query1) or die(print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));

// build a query to select records from table authorisation to echo out all queries
while ($group= sqlsrv_fetch_array($result1)  {
    $permissiongroup = $group[0];
    $permissionpages = $group[1];

    echo $permissiongroup;
    echo $permissionpages;
}
?>
```

I used two queries instead and it work. I am not sure why.

```
// build a query to select records from table authorisation to echo out all queries
$query1  = "SELECT permissiongroup FROM authorisation ORDER BY permissiongroup";

// execute the query you created above and store the result in a php variable
$result1 = sqlsrv_query($con, $query1) or die(print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));

// build a query to select records from table authorisation to echo out all queries
$query2  = "SELECT permissionpages FROM authorisation ORDER BY permissiongroup ";

// execute the query you created above and store the result in a php variable
$result2 = sqlsrv_query($con, $query2) or die(print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));

while (($group= sqlsrv_fetch_array($result1)) && ($page= sqlsrv_fetch_array($result2)) ) {
   $permissiongroup = $group['permissiongroup'];
   $pages = $page['permissionpages'];
   echo $permissiongroup;
   echo $pages;
}
```

Comment: not that good at php but try echo $group['columnname'];

Comment: Instead of `$group[0]`, you need to provide the name of the authorisation table field `$group['id_authorisation']`

Comment: prava: what do you mean by the table field? 
zxc:i tried before, didn't work :(

Comment: I mean the column name - table field name is same as column name. Hope answer of @rjv work for you.

Comment: I use two queries to echo out permissiongroup and pages and apprantly it worked. I don't know why it doesn't work when I use one query for it.Thanks anyway.

Comment: @Jolene, can u please put here the separate queries you are talking about in your comment, which you have tried. That will help us more to catch the issue.

Comment: @SuvenduShekharGiri I have updated it on my question. Thank you

Comment: @Jolene, can you try writing a complete query with column names instead of just `SELECT * FROM ` like `SELECT permissiongroup,permissionpages FROM authorisation;`. This may resolve your problem.

Comment: Just a FYI - this most likely won't solve it, but it looks like you are missing a ) from while ($group= sqlsrv_fetch_array($result1)  {. It should be while ($group= sqlsrv_fetch_array($result1))  {

Comment: I added already but it seems like it doesn't affect :( thanks anyway :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
<?php
// build a query to select records from table authorisation to echo out all queries
$query1 = "SELECT permissiongroup,permissionpages FROM authorisation ORDER BY permissiongroup";

// execute the query you created above and store the result in a php variable
$result1= sqlsrv_query($con, $query1) or die(print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));

// build a query to select records from table authorisation to echo out all queries
while ($group= sqlsrv_fetch_array($result1))  {
    $permissiongroup=$group['permissiongroup'];
    $permissionpages=$group['permissionpages'];

    echo $permissiongroup;
    echo $permissionpages;
}
?>
```

**Explanation (If this is the solution):**
If this resolves your problem, it means `permissiongroup` and `permissionpages` are not the first two consecutive  columns of the table `authorisation`. `select * from [tablename]` will always return the resulset with column names in the same order as present in the table structure. It is advised to use column names instead `*` to increase performance and many more conflicts like this.

**ELSE**
In case this doesn't help, please let me know.

Comment: Thank you so much for the detailed explanation. I've did what you told me to but instead, error message came out.
Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => IMSSP [SQLSTATE] => IMSSP [1] => -14 [code] => -14 [2] => An invalid parameter was passed to sqlsrv_query. [message] => An invalid parameter was passed to sqlsrv_query. ) )